# Matplotlib subplots: legend and axis-scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am plotting 4 subplots (i.e 2 rows 2 columns) in this way:

```
fig1= plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(221)
ax1.errorbar((r1),(xi1),fmt='',yerr=(low_err_1,upp_err_1),ls='none',color='black')
ax1.scatter((r1),(xi1),c='red',marker="o",s=30,label= r'$\xi(r)$ $0.0<z<0.5$')
ax1.plot((r1),(curve_y_1),'--',label='fit $0.0<z<0.5$')
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(222)
ax2.errorbar((r2),(xi2),fmt='',yerr=(low_err_2,upp_err_2),ls='none',color='black')
ax2.scatter((r2),(xi2),c='blue',marker="o",s=30,label=r'$\xi(r)$ $0.5<z<1.0$')
ax2.plot((r2),(curve_y_2),'--',label='fit $0.5<z<1.0$')
ax2.set_xscale('log')
ax2.set_yscale('log')

ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(223)
ax3.errorbar((r3),(xi3),fmt='',yerr=(low_err_3,upp_err_3),ls='none',color='black')
ax3.scatter((r3),(xi3),c='yellow',marker="o",s=30,label=r'$\xi(r)$ $1.0<z<1.5$')
ax3.plot((r3),(curve_y_3),'--',label='fit $1.0<z<1.5$')
ax3.set_xscale('log')
ax3.set_yscale('log')

ax4 = fig1.add_subplot(224)
ax4.errorbar((r4),(xi4),fmt='',yerr=(low_err_4,upp_err_4),ls='none',color='black')
ax4.scatter((r4),(xi4),c='black',marker="o",s=30,label=r'$\xi(r)$ $1.5<z<2.0$')
ax4.plot((r4),(curve_y_4),'--',label='fit $1.5<z<2.0$')
ax4.set_xscale('log')
ax4.set_yscale('log')
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to **add legends to all these subplots using a single (common) command**, instead of typing `ax1.legend(loc = 'best')`, `ax2.legend(loc = 'best')` and so on separately for each subplot?
2. I would like to **set log-scaling for each subplot using a single (common) command**. As you can see, now I am setting the axis-scales separately to log for each subplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define a axes formatting function:

```
def style_ax(ax):
   ax.legend(loc='best')
   ax.set_yscale('log')
   ax.set_xscale('log')
```

And than call it when finished:

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]:
   style_ax(ax)
```